# How to use a JProgressBar to keep track of Apache Derby processes

Tags: java, database, swing, derby, jprogressbar

So, I'm using Apache Derby to implement an Embedded database for a project. When loading/saving the database, especially when first creating the database, there is a long pause, for it to process. I was wondering if there was something that keeps track of this progress, so I can display it in a JProgressBar. Thanks in advance for your time and help.

Comment: Use a SwingWorker to execute what ever you're doing in the background, use its progress property support to help update the state of ui. Most of this assumes you know how many tasks you have to complete and can track which task you're up to

Comment: Thank you. I'll take a look into it, and let you know how it went.